# read the output of a command in perl

Tags: perl

I have an output after running a perl script that has several lines but the only lines I need is the gatewayName: and the statusCode: "failed".
ex.

EDIT: For example of 3 gateways, 2 fails 2 succeeded, I would only get one email.Here is the ouput after one batch finishes. I would like to get either one single email after all the batches are done or I can live with different emails per batch telling which one failed.

```
"Policy installation - Site-Firewalls"  failed  (100%)
tasks:
- uid: "e822c095-cb8b-4f8b-be51-c50a3bdf6aad"
  type: "task"
  domain:
    uid: "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
    name: "SMC User"
    domain-type: "domain"
  task-id: "97be087a-fad4-49ca-adc0-6fa0e32b4518"
  task-name: "Policy installation - Site-Firewalls"
  status: "failed"
  progress-percentage: 100
  start-time:
    posix: 1689859245449
    iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:20-0400"
  last-update-time:
    posix: 1689859512075
    iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:25-0400"
  suppressed: false
  task-details:
  - uid: "aa342b56-2f4d-4354-a491-b89812b9bf65"
    name: null
    domain:
      uid: "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
      name: "SMC User"
      domain-type: "domain"
    color: "black"
    statusCode: "succeeded"
    statusDescription: "Succeeded"
    taskNotification: "e822c095-cb8b-4f8b-be51-c50a3bdf6aad"
    gatewayId: "b74b22ba-cd75-4698-99b9-cc897f501fc1"
    policyId: "e539bfb8-6c3c-4835-a124-53a1b616f9aa"
    fastInstallStatus:
      worksessionId: "3baf8bc3-52ad-42df-be15-37b5ac2aa336"
      gatewayId: "b74b22ba-cd75-4698-99b9-cc897f501fc1"
      policyId: "e539bfb8-6c3c-4835-a124-53a1b616f9aa"
      status: "blade_not_supported"
      detailedReason: []
    runningStages: []
    waitingStages: []
    stagesInfo:
    - type: "info"
      stage: "legacy policy load"
      messages:
      - type: "info"
        message: "Threat Prevention Policy installation was canceled for:"
    cluster: false
    meta-info:
      validation-state: "ok"
      last-modify-time:
        posix: 1689859474791
        iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:24-0400"
      last-modifier: "System"
      creation-time:
        posix: 1689859246735
        iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:20-0400"
      creator: "System"
    tags: []
    icon: "General/globalsNa"
    comments: ""
    display-name: ""
    customFields: null
    gatewayName: "SF-Test1"
    revision: "3baf8bc3-52ad-42df-be15-37b5ac2aa336""
- uid: "a61261c0-6f40-4a89-a2b4-ff96c097c703"
    name: null
    domain:
      uid: "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
      name: "SMC User"
      domain-type: "domain"
    color: "black"
    statusCode: "succeeded"
    statusDescription: "Succeeded"
    taskNotification: "e822c095-cb8b-4f8b-be51-c50a3bdf6aad"
    gatewayId: "786eae4e-4f10-46f5-b0ef-effe426d828e"
    clusterGroupId: "1e34b75a-4a79-4306-97a7-763189253649"
    policyId: "e539bfb8-6c3c-4835-a124-53a1b616f9aa"
    fastInstallStatus:
      worksessionId: "3baf8bc3-52ad-42df-be15-37b5ac2aa336"
      gatewayId: "1e34b75a-4a79-4306-97a7-763189253649"
      policyId: "e539bfb8-6c3c-4835-a124-53a1b616f9aa"
      status: "blade_not_supported"
      detailedReason: []
    runningStages: []
    waitingStages: []
    stagesInfo: []
    cluster: false
    meta-info:
      validation-state: "ok"
      last-modify-time:
        posix: 1689859470158
        iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:24-0400"
      last-modifier: "System"
      creation-time:
        posix: 1689859246716
        iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:20-0400"
      creator: "System"
    tags: []
    icon: "General/globalsNa"
    comments: ""
    display-name: ""
    customFields: null
    gatewayName: "SF-Test1"
    revision: "3baf8bc3-52ad-42df-be15-37b5ac2aa336"
  - uid: "b2d97e39-8d7a-447f-a10b-4cc52d562197"
    name: null
    domain:
      uid: "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
      name: "SMC User"
      domain-type: "domain"
    color: "black"
    statusCode: "failed"
    statusDescription: "Failed"
    taskNotification: "e822c095-cb8b-4f8b-be51-c50a3bdf6aad"
    gatewayId: "cca50637-eed9-4dbd-b64f-1f368e2882d8"
    policyId: "e539bfb8-6c3c-4835-a124-53a1b616f9aa"
    fastInstallStatus:
      worksessionId: "3baf8bc3-52ad-42df-be15-37b5ac2aa336"
      gatewayId: "cca50637-eed9-4dbd-b64f-1f368e2882d8"
      policyId: "e539bfb8-6c3c-4835-a124-53a1b616f9aa"
      status: "blade_not_supported"
      detailedReason: []
    runningStages: []
    waitingStages: []
    stagesInfo:
    - type: "err"
      stage: "legacy policy load"
      messages:
      - type: "err"
        message: "Policy installation had failed due to an internal error. If the problem persists please contact Check Point support"
    cluster: false
    meta-info:
      validation-state: "ok"
      last-modify-time:
        posix: 1689859511828
        iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:25-0400"
      last-modifier: "System"
      creation-time:
        posix: 1689859246704
        iso-8601: "2023-07-20T09:20-0400"
      creator: "System"
    tags: []
    icon: "General/globalsNa"
    comments: ""
    display-name: ""
    customFields: null
    gatewayName: "SF-Test3"
    revision: "3baf8bc3-52ad-42df-be15-37b5ac2aa336"
```

Here is my code

```
my $results = qx/$args/;  ## -----This is when the command is executed.
print $results;


          ###DO I NEED TO DO A FOR LOOP ?? How do I say if it fails look for the gateway?
        for ($results) 
        {

        if  ($results =~ /failed/) {
                #my @array  = split("\n", $results);
                #my $len = @array;
                #my $gw1 = $array[$len-1];
                #my @gw = split(/:/,$gw1);

        push  (@fails, $results);
     


        }
    }
## Send the report via e-mail
if (@fails){
  #  my ($fails) = @_;
#my $gateway=$gw[1];
    my $sendmail = '/sbin/sendmail -t';
#print "this is gateway $gateway";
open (SENDMAIL, "|$sendmail") or die "Cannot open sendmail: $!";
print SENDMAIL "From:" . 'admin@test.com';
print SENDMAIL "\n";
print SENDMAIL "To:" . 'email@gmail.com';
print SENDMAIL "\n";
print SENDMAIL "Subject: " . " Failed IPS Clusters\n";
print SENDMAIL "\n";
print SENDMAIL @fails;
close (SENDMAIL);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When used in list context, `qx` returns a list of lines of output, instead of everything all in one string. That can then be looped over like usual:

```perl
my @results = qx/$args/;
my ($gateway, $status);
for my $line (@results) {
  if ($line =~ /gatewayName: "(.*)"/) {
    $gateway = $1;
  } elsif ($line =~ /statusCode: "(.*)"/) {
    $status = $1;
  }
}
```

---

Good practice is to use lexical filehandles and the [3-argument form of `open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open):

```perl
open my $SENDMAIL, "|-", "/sbin/sendmail -t"
  or die "Unable to open pipe to sendmail: $!\n";
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure *what* you want to extract from the command output; at the start of the question you say you need the gatewayName and statusCode fields, but your code seems to capture the entire output if the string `failed` is present somewhere in it. I went with the description, not the code.

Comment: Might also consider using one of the modules available in CPAN for sending emails instead of piping to `sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can extract content from the multiline string:

```
my $output = <<'END';
name: "SMC User"
      domain-type: "domain"
    color: "black"
    statusCode: "failed"
    statusDescription: "Failed"
customFields: null
    gatewayName: "test-gateway"
    revision: "a26546f2-2328-427d-b2f2-8b1411d09acc"
END

my $status_code;
my $gateway_name;
for my $line (split /\n/, $output) {
    if ($line =~ /^\s*statusCode:\s+"([^"]+?)"/) {
        $status_code = $1;
    }
    if ($line =~ /^\s*gatewayName:\s+"([^"]+?)"/) {
        $gateway_name = $1;
    }
}

if ($status_code eq "failed") {
    # Send the report via e-mail
    open (my $SENDMAIL, '|-', '/sbin/sendmail', '-t') or die "Cannot open sendmail: $!";
    #... print headers and subjects as before..
    print $SENDMAIL "$gateway_name failed\n";
    close $SENDMAIL;
}
```

Comment: to Push it to sendmail do I have to do push ($status_code, $gateway_name); ?

Comment: you mean this line: `push  (@fails, $results);`. How do you want to include that information in the mail? Please show the expected result

Comment: I just need an email saying which Gateway failed. On this example it will be "test-gateway"

Comment: Can you try something like: `print SENDMAIL "$gateway_name failed";`

Comment: See my updated answer, for an example

Comment: Thanks Hakon, the only issue is that the output has several gateways and fails and when this happens only 1 or the last gateway on the output sends the email w a single gateway.  I wanted to have all the gateways that fails in one single email

Comment: *"the only issue is that the output has several gateways"* For a single batch (`mgmt_cli` call), or for all batches? Maybe you could update your question with some examples?

Comment: I put an EDIT to the code to give you an example

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is not clear if there are 4 or 5 gateways in your example, the last one (number 5 with name `test-gateway` also has a different formatting the previous 4 gateways.

Comment: all of the gateways have "SF-gatewayname" ....and I do batches of 25. the output is longer with other parameters but I don't need them I'm only interested on the failed and the gateway name for all of the batch.

Comment: so the output you show will contain 25 blocks, each for a separate gateway? And within each block there is always a single line with "statusCode: ..." ?

Comment: the output will be all together so it will be 25 status codes and status descriptions. if it is successful message is "Succeeded" and if it fails "Failed" for each of the gateways. Let me send you the whole output of 2 firewalls, one fails and one succeeded. I will put it on the code. This will be an example of only doing the push for 2 gateways.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We should continue the discussion in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254596/discussion-between-user1026398-and-hakon-haegland).

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then it is, you are running a command `$args` in your Perl script and storing the output in `$results`. And now you want to process this and get the value of `statusCode` and `gatewayName` to process further.

Here is what you can do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Execute the command and capture the output
my $results = qx/$args/;

# Initialize variables to store the extracted values
my $statusCode;
my $gatewayName;

# Split the output into lines and process each line
foreach my $line (split /\n/, $results) {
    if ($line =~ /statusCode: "([^"]+)"/) {
        $statusCode = $1;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /gatewayName: "([^"]+)"/) {
        $gatewayName = $1;
    }
}

# Print the extracted values
print "Gateway Name: $gatewayName\n";
print "Status Code: $statusCode\n";

# Check if $statusCode is "failed" to send email
if ($statusCode eq 'failed') {
    # your code here to send email
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have several gateways but when a couple fail it only sends me an email with one and usually is the last one that appears in the output.